# How many half-squares can cover a square?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Let $I$ be a set of size $2n$. Given any subset $S\subset I$ of size $n$, we call $S^2=S\times S$ a half-square.

**Question**: How many half-squares can cover the whole square $I^2=I\times I$?

Denote the minimal number in question by $c(2n)$. (It is easy to see that $c(2)$ doesn't make sense; $c(4)=6$, since each upper off-diagonal element must in a half-square.)

Comment: This is an interesting question! I'm curious, what is the source of it?

Comment: @Rahul I have this question when I want to divide some pair-wisely work with super-large sets into sub-works(on computer) .

Comment: If $n$ is even you can reuse the $c(4)=6$ strategy: divide $I$ into $4$ blocks of $n/2$ elements each, and take all $6$ pairs of blocks as your subsets. This gives you an upper bound of $6$.

Comment: When $n = 2k$ is even, $c(2n) \le 6$ (split $I$ into 4 parts of size $k$, there are 6 ways to combine pair of two parts to form $S$ of size $n = 2k$). When $n = 2k+1$ is odd, $c(2n) \le 7$ (split $I$ into 4 parts, 2 parts has size $k$ and another 2 parts has size $k+1$, There are 5 ways to combine pairs to form $S$ with size $\le n = 2k+1$. You can use two more half-square to cover elements from the two parts with size $k+1$ )

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments of Rahul and achille hui, I suppose I figured out how to solve the problem. The answer is $c(4k)=6$ and $c(4k+2)=7$.

Let me show that $c(4k)=6$. The proof of $c(4k+2)=7$ is similar.

It is obviously that $c(4k)>(4k)^2/(2k)^2=4$. Using the block trick suggested by Rahul, we can cover the square by 6 half-squares. It remains to show that $c(4k)\ne 5$.

Suppose in the contrary that 5 can do the job. WOLOG, suppose the half-square  $[1,...,2k]^2$ is chosen, we have 4 half-squares left. Consider the set $J=[1,...,2k]\times [2k+1,....,4k]$. We assert that any half-square $S^2$ can cover mostly $k^2$ elements of $J$. Let $x=\#(S\cap[1,...,2k])$. The assertion follows from $S^2\cap J = x*(2k-x)\le k^2$. Hence $J$ needs the remaining 4 half-squares to be covered. It is clear that this covering must be exactly what we had by the block trick. Therefore, the given five half-squares are all the same as that given by the block trick, they cannot cover the whole square. QED.